# pass MongoDB aggregation result back to route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I read though several aggregation articles, but I'm still coming up short.

The aggregation is to test whether the element is in the document. If it returns back a result that is not an empty array then I know to "check" the box.

Here's the code I have so far, along with some comments of what I've tried.

```
router.get("/challenge/:challengeId", requireLogin, function(req, res) {

    var challengeId = req.params.challengeId;

    var isSolved = function(challengeId){
      console.log("in the aggregation: ", challengeId); // returns challengeId
      User.aggregate([
    //var isSolved = User.aggregate([
        { $match: {"solvedChallenges": { "challenge": challengeId } } },
        { $project: {
          userName: 1 }
        }
      ],
      function(err, results){
        console.log("this is the result: ", results); // logs a result if the there is one, and [] if there is no result.
        return results; // Trying to pass the results back to the /challenge/:challengeID route.
      });
    }

    //line below should return something like: []
    // or [ { _id: 56f5544bc171b1b8663bb15f, userName: 'John' } ]
    console.log("is solved is: ", isSolved(challengeId)); 
...



});
```

I'm trying to get the results, set them to a variable, and see if that variable is truthy. If truthy,then I'll check the box, if falsey, then keep it unchecked.

Also, If I'm doing something terribly wrong, I'd love to receive feedback.

Comment: What is the question? You have code outside of the callback that "looks like" you expect it to occur in serial order. It does not. Put your code inside the result callback where it should be. Are you seriously asking how to tell if an array is empty? This is what your question comes down to. Moreover, an `.aggregate()` just using `$match` and `$project` is not necessary. Just use `.find()` or better yet for your purpose, `.findOne({ "solvedChallenges.challenge": challengeId },function(err,doc) { ... })`. Which should also highlight another common error in your code. Too many problems here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a value in User.aggregate()'s callback won't return it to the caller.  So isSolved() needs a callback as the 2nd argument to pass the value back to the caller.  Something like this:

```
router.get("/challenge/:challengeId", requireLogin, function(req, res) {

    var challengeId = req.params.challengeId;

    var isSolved = function(challengeId, callback){  // <<=== pass callback here
        console.log("in the aggregation: ", challengeId); // returns challengeId
        User.aggregate([
                    //var isSolved = User.aggregate([
                    { $match: {"solvedChallenges": { "challenge": challengeId } } },
                    { $project: {
                        userName: 1 }
                    }
                ],
                function(err, results){
                    console.log("this is the result: ", results); // logs a result if the there is one, and [] if there is no result.
                    callback(err, results); // <<=== call callback here to return
                });
    };

    //line below should return something like: []
    // or [ { _id: 56f5544bc171b1b8663bb15f, userName: 'John' } ]
    //console.log("is solved is: ", isSolved(challengeId));

    isSolved(challengeId, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            // return error here using res
        } else {
            // do something with results and 
            // return it using res
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for actually answering the question and being helpful! Much appreciated!